# get-aduser from csv file lastlogon passwordexpire

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory, passwords

The below script gives me the proper input for one account, when multiple accounts are added it does not work. How can I get it to work for all user accounts listed in the csv file?

```
$csv = import-csv "c:\users.csv"

foreach($user in $csv){
$Displayname = $user.Displayname
Get-aduser -filter {displayname -eq $displayname}`
-Properties displayName,employeeID,mail, "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed","lastLogonTimestamp" |`
 select "Displayname","Enabled",@{Name="PasswordExpiryDate";Expression={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")}},@{N='LastLogonTime'; E={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.lastLogonTimestamp)}},SamAccountName,employeeID,mail |`
Export-Csv "c:\temp\users1.csv"
}
```

Comment: Export-Csv "c:\temp\users1.csv" -append ?

Comment: The -append switch did work

Comment: Great.  I've added it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `-append` switch to your `export-csv` otherwise the file will be overwritten each time it is looped over leaving details of only the last user in the list

```
Export-Csv "c:\temp\users1.csv" -append
```